# accordion in joomla module for form inserted from jumi

Tags: jquery, joomla, module, mootools, accordion

I'm having a bit of trouble with this one.  the plugins for accordions all seem to be for articles.  I have a fairly simple form that is included in a .php file that is included in the module via a jumi reference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the accordian article it is just a matter of adding the position (alias) of that module.  Let's say we have a Jumi module with alias `foo`.  Just type this in the article editor:

```
{loadposition foo}
```